# How to set maximum length of input tag using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, if-statement

I have a number pad and `<input>` .

I am typing the Mobile number in the input tag using the number pad below
I want set the maximum `length` of the input to 8 
I used several method but of them the maximum length will work only if type from the keyboard not working when I use the number pad
Can some one help me

I have tried

```
$(".num-text").attr({
  "max" : 10,        
  "min" : 10          
});
```

This is my code

## `html`

```
    <div id="zeroseven">07<input id="numBox" class="num-text" name='tel' oninput="javascript:  this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" type = "number" maxlength = "8"/></div><br><br>
<div class="numpad">
        <button class="numbers" value="1">1</button>
        <button class="numbers" value="2">2</button>
        <button class="numbers" value="3">3</button>
        <button class="numbers" value="4">4</button>
        <button class="numbers" value="5">5</button>
        <button class="numbers" value="6">6</button>
        <button class="numbers" value="7">7</button>
        <button class="numbers" value="8">8</button>
        <button class="numbers" value="9">9</button>
        <button id="clear" class="numbers" >&larr;</button>
        <button class="numbers" value="0">0</button>
        <button id="delete" class="numbers">DEL</button>
</div>
```

## jquery

```
         //Onlick numpad button
        $( ".numbers" ).on('click',function(evt) {
            $(".num-text").val(($('.num-text').val()) + (this.value));
            var length = $('.num-text').val().length;
            if (length > 8){

            }
        });
```

I need it so that if the `length >8` it should stop typing more numbers after that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done 99.9%

```
 $(".num-text").val(($('.num-text').val()) + (this.value));
```

Just put this into if case

```js
        $( ".numbers" ).on('click',function(evt) {            
            var length = $('.num-text').val().length;
            if (length < 8){
            $(".num-text").val(($('.num-text').val()) + (this.value));
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="zeroseven">07<input id="numBox" class="num-text" name='tel' oninput="javascript:  this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);"
            type = "number"
            maxlength = "8"/></div><br><br>
            <div class="numpad">
                    <button class="numbers" value="1">1</button>
                    <button class="numbers" value="2">2</button>
                    <button class="numbers" value="3">3</button>
                    <button class="numbers" value="4">4</button>
                    <button class="numbers" value="5">5</button>
                    <button class="numbers" value="6">6</button>
                    <button class="numbers" value="7">7</button>
                    <button class="numbers" value="8">8</button>
                    <button class="numbers" value="9">9</button>
                    <button id="clear" class="numbers" >&larr;</button>
                    <button class="numbers" value="0">0</button>
                    <button id="delete" class="numbers">DEL</button>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, you can use below logic.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".numbers").on('click', function(evt) {
    var length = $('.num-text').val().length;
    if (length >= 8) {
      evt.preventDefault();
    } else {
      $(".num-text").val(($('.num-text').val()) + (this.value));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="zeroseven">07<input id="numBox" class="num-text" name='tel' oninput="javascript:  this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" type="number" maxlength="8" /></div><br><br>
<div class="numpad">
  <button class="numbers" value="1">1</button>
  <button class="numbers" value="2">2</button>
  <button class="numbers" value="3">3</button>
  <button class="numbers" value="4">4</button>
  <button class="numbers" value="5">5</button>
  <button class="numbers" value="6">6</button>
  <button class="numbers" value="7">7</button>
  <button class="numbers" value="8">8</button>
  <button class="numbers" value="9">9</button>
  <button id="clear" class="numbers">&larr;</button>
  <button class="numbers" value="0">0</button>
  <button id="delete" class="numbers">DEL</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Min and max attribute does not work for html5 input type number
`<input type="text" pattern="\d*" maxlength="10" />`  and also attach to javascript event to it to ensure the value is a number as a fallback to the pattern attribute